# Detecting gestures with Kinect makes Unity freeze

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm trying to detect a custom made gesture with Kinect and Unity. It works for one person but Unity will freeze and require a reboot when there are more than one person detected.

```
void Update()
{
    if (BodySourceManager == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _BodyManager = BodySourceManager.GetComponent<BodySourceManager>();
    if (_BodyManager == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Kinect.Body[] data = _BodyManager.GetData();
    if (data == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _VGB_Source = _BodyManager.GetRecordedGesturesData();
    detectedGestures = _BodyManager.GetDetectedGestures();
    List<ulong> trackedIds = new List<ulong>();
    foreach (var body in data)
    {
        if (body == null)
        {
            _BodyManager.SetVGBReaderPauseState(true);
            continue;
        }
        if (body.IsTracked)
        {
            _BodyManager.SetVGBReaderPauseState(false);
            trackedIds.Add(body.TrackingId);
            _VGB_Source.TrackingId = body.TrackingId;
            DetectTargetGestureOnBodies("SwipeRight", body.TrackingId.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In a separate BodySourceManager class, I open the kinect sensor and initializes the VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource object. From **this script** which is attached to an empty GameObject, I want to see if the gesture "SwipeRight" is detected.

Does anyone have any ideas to why Unity is freezing up with multiple bodies, or if anyone has a sample that is known to work with multiple bodies it will be very welcome.

Comment: https://rfilkov.com/2015/01/25/kinect-v2-tips-tricks-examples/ - maybe it can help you

Comment: @16per9 thanks, let me take a look at that link.